# 0Dagger 2: MVVM unable to scope a module

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I am new to the MVVM and Dagger and I am trying ot implement MVVM with Dagger 2 and Butterknife in my app. unfortunatelly I get the following error:

```
error: @Modules cannot be scoped. Did you mean to scope a method instead?
```

I get this error when I try to make my 'ViewModelModule' singleton. Here is my class:

```
@Singleton
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule { ... }
```

I am refering 'ViewModelModule' in my ' ApplicationModule ' which looks like so:

```
 @Singleton
 @Module(includes = ViewModelModule.class)
 public class ApplicationModule { ... }
```

If I remove the 'Singleton' annotation everithing works fine. But what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `@Singleton` for modules

Comment: @Onik but wont that cause issues later in the app? I see a lot of examples using MVVM and Dagger 2 together and in each of them the 'ViewModelModule' is singleton

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modules mustn't be singletons, singletons could be the dependencies that modules provides. For instance:

```
@Module
public class ViewModelModule { 
    @Provides 
    @Singleton
    public String provideFoo() {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

So, remove `@singleton` annotation from your modules declaration.

Comment: I am following this guide https://github.com/brunohauck/CHALLENGE/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/arctouch/codechallenge/module/ViewModelModule.java
and as you can see the guy is making the modules Singleton which is a bit confusing for me. But you are sure it is perfectly fine for the modules not to be singleton?

Comment: I've never used scopes in my modules and I don't know even if that makes sense. I use scopes to define my components/subcomponents scopes and to define the scopes of the dependencies that my modules provides.